# How many different combinations are there fore selecting 15 chocolates?

Tags: probability

I think this exam question is awkwardly worded, so I want to run it by you guys:

A particular box of chocolates contains large quantities of each of 7 different kinds of chocolates. After a hard day at work, Allison decides to sit down and eat 15. Assuming she doesn't care about the order in which she eats them, how many different ways are there for her to select her chocolates?

I say the answer is 7^15, but my friends and I are unsure. They say C(15,7). Help us out!

Answer (score 3):

$C(15,7)$ is the number of ways to choose $7$ items from $15$ possibilities (under certain conditions).  Now in this case there are not $15$ things to choose from and Allison is not choosing $7$ things so I think your friends are just guessing!

Your answer is closer but still not correct: $7^{15}$ is the number of ways to make $15$ choices from $7$ things (for example $15$ choices from $7$ kinds of chocolate), if choosing the same item more than once is permissible (which is true in this problem) **and** the order of choices is important (which is not true in this problem - "she doesn't care about the order in which she eats them").

To solve the problem correctly imagine the following scenario.  Allison chooses all $15$ chocolates before she eats any, then lays them out in a row on the table.  To make sure she doesn't forget which are which she puts all the first type together, then a knife on the table to separate them from  the second type, and so on.  For example, if she decided to eat $10$ of the first type, $5$ of the fourth type and none of the others, her table would look like
$$cccccccccc|||ccccc|||\ .$$
If she decided to have two of each plus an extra type 6 it would be
$$cc|cc|cc|cc|cc|ccc|cc\ .$$
So, we can solve the problem by counting the number of ways to arrange fifteen $c$s and six $|$s in a row.  To do this, note that there are $21$ places altogether and we have to choose which $6$ of them hold $|$s.  We cannot choose the same place twice, and the order of places does not matter, so the number of choices is $C(21,6)$.

Comment: oh my bad. you're right.

Comment: Nice exposition of Stars and Bars!

Comment: Yes they are different - your second example would be $10$ of the first type and $5$ of the *second* type, not the fourth.